# Why does Python Set automatically re-sorting my inputted set?

Tags: python

below is my code, and when I print or use the Python set, it automatically re-sort my item, why does this happen?

```
a = {9,40,49}
print(a)

{40, 9, 49}
```

Below is notebook printed image.

[image: Jupyter Notebook Auto Re-sorting]

Comment: Sets are unordered

Comment: Oh! Been trying to figure out why for such a long time, thank you.

Comment: How much time exactly? A simple "python set order" google would reveal the answer

Comment: i've been searching "python set re-ordering my list" but not luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are an unordered data structure. However, depending on your use case, it might be appropriate to use a different data type such as list.